# how to handle license header in every file

Tags: doxygen

I am working on documenting a fairly large, existing C code. Each source file has a multi-paragraph copyright and license header at the top that I have to keep. When I produce the documentation in doxygen, this clutters up the documentation.

So far I have tried creating a custom alias, suggested from searching here. I haven't been able to find a way to handle multiple paragraphs, though, with the custom command. What I would really like is a hidden "expandable" section at the bottom of the page for the file or something similar.

What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it necessary that the copyright and license comment be "documentation comments?" Typically they are not. The only reason to have documentation comments (i.e., they start with `///` or `/**`) is because you want them to show up in the documentation somewhere.

If there is some reason they need to be documentation comments, then look at [ENABLED_SECTIONS](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_enabled_sections) and the [cond](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdcond) command.

Comment: I suppose keeping the license header out of the documentation is what most people do? The ENABLED_SECTIONS and cond commend allow you to conditionally control processing portions of code or comments. However, I still can't find a way to create a new "section" in the documentation page with multiple paragraphs.

Comment: Yes, I have never seen the license header be a "documentation comment." Keep in mind that with doxygen you are always documenting some "construct" of your software; e.g., class, function, typedef, file, etc. So if you need a comment to go into a "section", you need to have that section be in the context of the element you are commenting. Given your question, my guess is you want the section to be for the file? I think you would be better off using a normal documentation comment for a file with a hyperlink to the license text. If you need help with that, I think another question is in order.